# How to input a condition into df.assign?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following datatype:

```
id         arrival_time         departure_time         start  end  capacity

Train A          0                  2016-05-19 08:25:00   A     B    2
Train A   2016-05-19 13:50:00       2016-05-19 16:00:00   B     H    2
Train A   2016-05-19 21:25:00       2016-05-20 07:25:00   C     I    3
Train B          0                  2016-05-24 12:50:00   D     J    3
Train B   2016-05-24 18:30:00       2016-05-25 20:00:00   E     K    2
Train B   2016-05-26 12:15:00       2016-05-26 19:45:00   K     L    3
```

I would like to add a column called source and sink and if the time difference between arrival and departure is less than 3 hours, the source is the starting of the trip and the sink is only when the trip breaks (ie when time_difference is more than 3 hours,

```
time difference   source     sink
     -              A         H
     02:10:00       A         H
     10:00:00       C         I
     -              D         J
     01:30:00       E         L
     19:30:00       E         L
```

So i use the following condition:

```
df = df.assign(timediff=(df.departure_time - df.arrival_time))
df = df.assign(source = np.where(df.timediff.dt.seconds / 3600 < 3, df.shift(1).start, df.start))
df = df.assign(sink = np.where(df.timediff.dt.seconds.shift(1) / 3600 > 3, df.shift(-1).end, df.end))
```

But I would like to implement this condition, only if the end of first line matches with start of second line, grouped by their id.

I used the following condition to implement this,

```
df = df.assign(timediff=(df.departure_time - df.arrival_time))
n1= (df['end'] == df ['start'].shift() & df.timediff.dt.seconds / 3600 < 3)
df = df.assign(source = np.where(n1, df.shift(1).start, df.start))
df = df.assign(sink = np.where(n1, df.shift(-1).end, df.end))
```

But i get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hazy what your question is, so I'll just address the error you have been getting.

Your n1 calculation hinges on an expression `statement 1 & statement 2`, if you have written it correctly. Right now it executes: `df['end'] == (df['start'.shift() & df.timediff.dt.seconds / 3600 <3)`. Which compares a string (df['start'].shift()) to a boolean (df.timediff.dt.seconds/3600 < 3)

So the fix is to add brackets around your statements:

```
n1= ((df['end'] == df['start'].shift()) & (df.timediff.dt.seconds / 3600 < 3))
```

The last expression does not need brackets, as the expressions are executed back to front, but it never hurts to be explicit.